# call to ioexception throwing function

Tags: java, android, exception

I cannot call this function although it does throw amnd handle IOException

```
 public static String[] readtxt(String f) throws IOException{
    try{
     FileReader fileReader=new FileReader(f);
     BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fileReader);
     List<String> lines=new ArrayList<String>();
     String line=null;
     while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)lines.add(line);
     bufferedReader.close();
     return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    }catch(IOException e){return null;}     
}

 ...    
 private String[] truth=MainActivity.readtxt(file); 
 // ^ wont compile: Unhandled exception type IOException
```

Comment: create a function that doesn't throw an exception or add try/catch block around readtxt call. P.S. I don't see why you need to throw it, just remove "throws IOException".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your method as throwing IOExceptions;

```
public static String[] readtxt(String f) throws IOException
```

This means that any method that calls this method must deal with such exceptions (in a catch block), you are not dealing with them in the method calling this method and so this error is raised.

However, you **have** handled any IOExceptions that might be thrown. It is not nessissary (or correct) to claim that the method could throw an IOException because it never will. Simply remove `throws IOException`.

You have handled the exception by returning null, this may or may not be correct depending on your implementation. On an IOException a null will be returned and the program will continue as if nothing happened, you may alternatively want to give an error message but as I say this depends on your exact circumstances

Answer (score 2):

You either need to handle the Exception your method is throwing like this

```
try{ 
    private String[] truth = MainActivity.readtxt(file);
}catch(IOException ioe){
    // Handle Exception
}
```

Or you can remove the `throws` clause from your method definition like this

```
public static String[] readtxt(String f) {
```

Looking at your code, I really doubt if the method will actually throw any `IOException` since you already caught. Therefore you can remove that clause.

But if you really want to throw that, then you can either remove the try-catch in your method or do something like this in your catch block

```
catch(IOException ioe){
    // Throw IOE again
    throw new IOException(ioe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the exception like below

```
 try{ 
      private String[] truth=MainActivity.readtxt(file); 
 }catch(IOException exception){
      exception.printStackTrace()
 }
```

Comment: I think the return null isn't (nessissarily) a problem, the throws IOException is